# how make text clickable LinkMovementMethod?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I try to make links clickable but app crash after call method               content_new.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
I don't know what should I do ?!

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        parentv = new LinearLayout(mContext);
        parentv.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        parentv.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

        if (position == 0) {
            LayoutInflater header = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemBox = header.inflate(R.layout.details_news, null);

            share = (ImageView) itemBox.findViewById(R.id.share_icon);
            share.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            share.setClickable(true);
            share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    intent.setType("text/plain");
                    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
                            "http://k-islamyah.com/news/i/" + new_detail_id);
                    startActivity(Intent
                            .createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
                }
            });

            new_view = (TextView) itemBox.findViewById(R.id.new_view);
            new_comments = (TextView) itemBox
                    .findViewById(R.id.new_comments);
            new_like = (TextView) itemBox.findViewById(R.id.new_like);
            new_unlike = (TextView) itemBox.findViewById(R.id.new_unlike);
            new_date = (TextView) itemBox.findViewById(R.id.new_date);
            title_details_new = (TextView) itemBox
                    .findViewById(R.id.title_details_new);
            content_new = (TextView) itemBox.findViewById(R.id.content_new);
            image_details_new = (LinearLayout) itemBox
                    .findViewById(R.id.image_details_new);              

            img_details_like = (ImageView) itemBox
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_details_like);
            img_details_dislike = (ImageView) itemBox
                    .findViewById(R.id.img_details_dislike);
            comment_img = (ImageView) itemBox
                    .findViewById(R.id.comment_img);

            comment_img.setClickable(true);


            new_view.setPadding(2, 3, 0, 0);
            new_comments.setPadding(2, 3, 0, 0);
            new_like.setPadding(2, 3, 0, 0);
            new_unlike.setPadding(2, 3, 0, 0);

            int Viewed_num = (Integer.parseInt(Viewed) + 1);
            new_date.setText(CreatedDate);
            new_view.setText(Viewed_num + "");
            new_comments.setText(CommentsCount);
            new_like.setText(Liked);
            new_unlike.setText(UnLiked);
            title_details_new.setText(Title);

            content_new.setText(Html.fromHtml(Contents));
            content_new.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

            BitmapDrawable background = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
            image_details_new.setBackgroundDrawable(background);

            parentv.addView(itemBox);
        }



        return parentv;
    }
```

Log :

```
03-05 10:14:43.476: E/InputEventReceiver(30658): Exception dispatching input event.
03-05 10:14:43.476: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:995)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:962)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:290)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:212)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7677)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7392)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1983)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1435)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2459)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1931)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7572)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3909)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3804)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3403)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3453)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3422)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3507)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3430)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3564)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3403)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3453)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3422)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3430)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3403)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5445)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5425)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5396)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5519)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:133)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5478)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at java.lang.ref
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:995)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:962)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:290)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.text.style.URLSpan.onClick(URLSpan.java:62)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:212)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7677)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7392)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2216)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1957)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1983)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1435)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2459)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1931)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7572)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3909)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3804)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3403)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3453)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3422)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3507)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3430)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3564)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3403)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3453)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3422)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3430)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3403)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5445)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5425)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5396)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5519)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:182)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:133)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5478)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/AndroidRuntime(30658):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Metho
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at khawateer.eslamih.eslamic1712.HomePageActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(HomePageActivity.java:369)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2539)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:413)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:789)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:198)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5478)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:875)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:691)
03-05 10:14:46.156: E/AndroidRuntime(11815):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is line 369 in  `HomePageActivity.java:369`?

Comment: You might want to accept some answers as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:

```
LayoutInflater header = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

First problem is you are obtaining the `LayoutInflater` from a non-activity context and then using it to inflate the views. This is causing a RuntimeException. You can see it in your logs as "Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?"

Secondly you are initializing the `LayoutInflater` inside of your `getView()` method. I assume this is an adapter, so the `getView()` method will be called a lot of times, which will seriously impact your List/Grid scrolling speed.

A solution is to initialize the `LayoutInflater` in the constructor itself and use it to inflate your views in `getView()`.

```
class SampleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private LayoutInflater inflater
  // other stuff
    public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
      // other stuff
      inflater = ((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE));
    }

  // other methods

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      // use the inflater object you initialized in the constructor
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks I edit code like what you said but still have this problem 

 at android.text.method.LinkMovementMethod.onTouchEvent(LinkMovementMethod.java:212)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:7677)
03-05 10:14:43.506: E/MessageQueue-JNI(30658):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7392)


when I remove this line content_new.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());  code run correctly

Comment: Can you post what exception you are getting? And are you using the inflater that you initialized in the constructor?

Comment: yes I set inflater  in constractor and remove the code in getview and use new inflater  the initialize in contractor 

this is error :
03-05 11:34:20.186: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9328): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-05 11:34:20.226: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9328): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: 03-05 11:34:20.186: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9328): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
03-05 11:34:20.226: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9328): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
03-05 11:34:20.226: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9328):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:995)
03-05 11:34:20.226: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9328):  at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:962)
03-05 11:34:20.226: E/MessageQueue-JNI(9328):

Comment: Again, you probably aren't passing an activity context in your adapter. Try doing `new SampleAdapter(SomeActivity.this)` instead of `new SampleAdapter(getApplicationContext())`